# Why my dict methods works well without defining with extra `dict` argument ? [vim]

Tags: vim

My piece of code looks like:

```
:let ClassZ = {'author': "Juchen.Zeng"}
:function ClassZ.Print_author_name()
:    echo self.author
:endfunction

:function ClassZ.Change_author_name(arg1)
:    let self.author = a:arg1
:endfunction

:call ClassZ.Print_author_name()

Juchen.Zeng

:call ClassZ.Change_author_name('MarioLuisGarcia')
:call ClassZ.Print_author_name()

MarioLuisGarcia
```

And in vim's official doc, it says:

---

```
    :function uk2nl.translate(line) dict
    :  return join(map(split(a:line), 'get(self, v:val, "???")'))
    :endfunction
```

Let's first try it out:

```
    :echo uk2nl.translate('three two five one')
    drie twee ??? een
```

The first special thing you notice is the "dict" at the end of the ":function"
line.  This marks the function as being used from a Dictionary.  The "self"
local variable will then refer to that Dictionary.

---

Why in my examples, without extra `dict` argument, the self reference seems work well? Is this `dict` arg indispensable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dict` attribute is dispensable in this case, because defining and assigning function directly to dictionary implied `dict` attribute for  function, using `dict` attribute is not necessary anymore.

That type of functions are called [anonymous-function or numbered-function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#numbered-function).

In your example, you have defined two `ClassZ` keys, `Change_author_name` and `Print_author_name` which have values are [Funcref](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#Funcref).

You can verify it, using [function()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#function()):

```
:function ClassZ.Print_author_name
   function 394() dict
1  echo self.author
   endfunction
```

You can see, a `numbered-function - 394` had been created, with `dict` attribute.

Comment: Thank you. But, at which circumstance I'll need the extra dict argument? Does such kind of situation exists in vim7.4?

Comment: @Zen: Yes, when you define a normal function, then assign it to a dictionary later. See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#Dictionary-function